# solution to take in other hand pointer to NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data

in first loop i was take NSManaged object

```
    for (NSManagedObject *carrier in carriers)
    {
       // find one necessary carrier
    }
```

I need a transfer finded carrier object to second loop to using it for build inverse relationship.
I tryed to declare

```
NSManagedObject *currentCarrier;
```

and make

```
currentCarrier = carrier;
```

but has a error 
[NSManagedObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a98190

what is correct way to make transfer?

**SOLUTION**

Main issue what i can't directly using NSString object in forKey: 
Bellow is a code, which working fine if u have to using external string forKey:

```
[destinstionsListForSale setValue:importRowElement forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",importRowsName]];
```

Comment: You have not shown enough code here.  The error message occurs because you have sent `-copy` to an NSManagedObject.  None of what you have posted does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may have a scope error:

```
for (NSManagedObject *carrier in carriers)
{
   // find one necessary carrier
}
NSManagedObject *currentCarrier;
currentCarrier = carrier;
```

Try this?

```
NSManagedObject *currentCarrier;
for (NSManagedObject *carrier in carriers)
{
   // find one necessary carrier
   currentCarrier = carrier;
}
```

I can't tell without more code.

Comment: Your speculation would result in a compilation error, not a runtime exception, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: I was do a same as u propose to do. Main issue is i try to set value forKey as a string variable.

Comment: I was do a same as u propose to do. It's happened when i try to set value forKey as a string variable for NSManagedObject destinstionsListForSale                           [destinstionsListForSale setValue:importRowElement forKey:importRowsName];

Comment: try `setStringValue: forKey:`

Comment: -setStringValue:forKey method not found

Comment: NSManagedObject *destinstionsListForSale = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DestinationsListForSale"                                                       inManagedObjectContext:moc]; - this object where i add.

Comment: @Alex, what is the value of `importRowsName`?  It may be an invalid value for the key.

Comment: yep, i fix it when make changes in code. i don't know exactly how :) do u recommend to post all final code here?